# Use wine without user interaction

Tags: wine

I want to run a Windows executable (a console application) from a shell script. This script is part of a bigger project that automatically builds packages, so I need to avoid user interaction.

Actually I use something like this:

```
export WINEARCH=win64
export WINEPREFIX=/somewhere/$WINEARCH
wine pgen.exe
```

It basically works but with with the following problems:

1. If `WINEPREFIX` is empty (and this is the case in the first run), a dialog appears showing to wait for configuration. I'd like to avoid depending on an X server running.
2. If not previously installed, `wine` shows a window asking to install Gecko and requiring user intervention.
3. `WINEPREFIX` needs to be owned by the user calling wine, so I don't know how to provide a system-wide wrapper to run the above application.

Apart the latter issue (that I can live without), the other ones are blocking. At the end I just want to run a console application.

Comment: Try DOSBox (sudo apt-get install dosbox)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run `wine` with an empty `$DISPLAY`, it will skip displaying any dialogs and run without user interaction:

```
DISPLAY= wine pgen.exe
```

To avoid the prefix ownership issue, I generally point `WINEPREFIX` at a temporary directory so the prefix is re-created every time (but that's slow).

Comment: Unsetting `DISPLAY`also avoids to trigger other dialog windows: exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can "boot" your wine environment by running it from an X session once, letting it configure mono etc. After that, backup the entire `.wine` directory and use that as a base for each user who needs to run the console application.

You can use `xvfb` as a virtual X server; see [here](https://gist.github.com/jterrace/2911875) for an example how to start it automatically. Then `export DISPLAY=:1` before starting wine. I needed this to shut wine up about not having a display, even thouch I was only running a console executable. YMMV.

I'm not sure whether the `WINEPREFIX` tree needs to be owned by the user running wine, or just needs write permissions on certain locations (e.g. the `.reg` files, temporary locations).

Comment: Regardling the ownership I just retried and I can confirm you must own `WINEPREFIX` otherwise wine will refuse to start.